# How test an app link to an instant app as a closed test

Tags: google-play-services, release, android-instant-apps

I have tested successfully a debug version of an instant app that is called by an app link, e.g., https://domain/?q=1234567. I have created a release version and signed it with a "Create new" key. Upload to a new Closed Testing release fails, however, because the Bundle is signed "with the wrong key".

What am I doing wrong in trying to test a release version without Publishing publicly? Do I have to go forward to Publish and rely on my previous debug testing of the app link or is there a way to verify the app link operation in closed testing?"

Answer (score 1):

It took a lot of digging, but I found the answer here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig
It is the documentation for "Create and edit run/debug configurations".
It says:

> URL - Launch a URL that matches an intent filter in your app's
> manifest. When selected, the URL field appears below, where you can
> enter the URL.
>
> You must fill in this field to launch an Android Instant App. You may
> also use this to test your Android App Links.

This confirms that my successful testing of my app link to initiate my instant app proves it will work in release form when it is published.

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question, this helped a lot as I was stuck on a similar issue.